# How to train on multiple non uniform data sources

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation

I have financial data from multiple countries. When we started, the focus was only on US and our main training came from a US dataset which has 58 attributes out of which 27 were used for training. However, now that we are expanding, we have to generalize our models. When I look at data from other countries, the attributes are lesser but there are about 14 attributes common across all datasets. Moreover, The problem is that the size of data for other countries is very less (almost 30K rows) while our US dataset is about 8 million.

One solution is to use 14 attributes for all the data but our US model works very well and when we used 14 points, there accuracy wasn't that good.

What is the best way to use multiple sources of data for training?